# Animation in Imageview running out of memeory

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, asynchronous, imageview

I'm trying to create an animation. I have 3 images(14kb each), that I'm putting into an image view.Using the animation class's timer the  In my first implementation, android consistently runs out of memory and the application crashes. This is my code below

## First attempt

### Animation list (drawable.insert.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="550" /> 
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/a2" android:duration="550" /> 
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/a3" android:duration="550" />
</animation-list>
```

### starting the animation

```
private void startTheAnimations(final int alertType){
System.gc();
try{
final ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.animations);

if(alertType == INSERT){
image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.insert);
}

splashAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) image.getBackground();
splashAnimation.start();

}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I thought of trying an asynctask as shown below but this also crashes stating I cant set the background of an imageview outside of the UI-thread.This don't help because the ui thread is crashing due to a lack memory.

## Attempt 2 asynctask

```
public void startAnimation(){
final ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.animations);  
AnimationTask task = new AnimationTask(image);
task.execute(alertType);   
}

class AnimationTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean> {
private final ImageView image;

public AnimationTask(ImageView imageView) {
image = imageView;
}

// Decode image in background.
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
int alertType = params[0];
try{
if(alertType == INSERT){
image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.insert);
}
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean t) {
AnimationDrawable a =   (AnimationDrawable) image.getBackground();
a.start();

}
}
```

To end an already long question, does anyone know how I can get this animation to work properly?

Comment: attempt #1 is the proper one, post the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue by increasing the heap in the manifest of my activity

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```